# Git Not Pushing

Tags: git, github

So I have a project checkout out and the master branch points to one repo, while the site-development branch points to another repo.

The site-development branch points to a repo with a remote name of site.

When I do a `git pull site master` I see:

```
$ git pull site master
From github.com:AdamKyle/freya-framework-site
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
```

So when I do a `git push site master` I get:

```
$ git pull site master
From github.com:AdamKyle/freya-framework-site
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
vagrant@vagrantpress:/vagrant/wordpress/wp-content/themes/freya-theme$ git push site master 
To git@github.com:AdamKyle/freya-framework-site.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:AdamKyle/freya-framework-site.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Both this branch and the master branch are up to date. What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that your local copy of master is behind the master on "site".

I made two repos for demonstration:

```
$ git status
On branch asdf
nothing to commit, working directory clean

$ git pull site master
From file:///tmp/site
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.

$ git push site master
To file:///tmp/site
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'file:///tmp/site'
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
$
```

Local "asdf" is up-to-date with "site's" master, but my local master is not.

Pushing local "master" to "site" fails, since remote master is ahead.

Comment: Oh this would make sense, see I have it set up so one branch - master - pulls and pushes from origin master which is a repo. Then site master pulls and pushes on the site-development branch from a different repo. Which I thought you could do in git but apparently not.

Answer (score -1):

Use the --force flag.

```
git push site master --force
```

Comment: Can you explain why I would have to force push?

Comment: Is your local branch current?

Comment: Both my master and this current branch are up to date with the head. when I pull it states its already up to date.

Comment: Are you SURE that your local master is up to date? What does "git diff site/master master" say?

Comment: It really sounds like you are fetching and merging site/master into your current working branch. And then you are trying to push your local master to site, which gets rejected because it is behind.

Comment: (Keep in mind that "git pull site master" will not update your local master, if you are not currently on master.)

Comment: @folkol thats fine, I wanted git pull site master to update the site-development branch, which it did. the force push worked. but I fear it was the wrong thing to do ... Both branches are up to date with their respective repo destinations.

Comment: Yes, I understand that you wanted to merge remote master into your working branch. But your push was "my local, old, version of master to remote master".

Comment: I will post an answer with my explanation instead.